# Oracle/SQL 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm still somewhat new at sql and databases. I feel like I am missing something really simple but I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error.

```
ORA-00904: "Total Pay": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
  with computed_pay as (select J.job_code,
                               case
                                 when J.pay_type = 'salary' then J.pay_rate
                                 when J.pay_type = 'wage' then J.pay_rate * 1920
                                 else null
                               end "Total Pay"
                          from job J),
       current_pay as (SELECT per_id,
                              "Total Pay",
                              primary_sector
                         FROM works
                         NATURAL JOIN job
                         NATURAL JOIN company
                         NATURAL JOIN job_profile),
       old_pay as (SELECT per_id,
                          "Total Pay",
                          primary_sector
                     FROM works
                     NATURAL JOIN job
                     NATURAL JOIN company
                     NATURAL JOIN job_profile),
       num_increase as (SELECT *
                          FROM current_pay C
                          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT I.per_id
                                          FROM old_pay I
                                          WHERE C.per_id = I.per_id) AND
                                "Total Pay" > all (SELECT "Total Pay"
                                                     FROM old_pay O
                                                     WHERE C.per_id = O.per_id)),
       num_decrease as (SELECT *
                          FROM current_pay C
                          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT I.per_id
                                          FROM old_pay I
                                          WHERE C.per_id = I.per_id) AND
                                "Total Pay" < all (SELECT "Total Pay"
                                                     FROM old_pay O
                                                     WHERE C.per_id = O.per_id))
select (case
          when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM num_increase) <> 0 then
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM num_decrease) /
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM num_increase)
        end) as ratio 
  from dual;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the DDL for the `works`, `job`, `company`, and `job_profile` tables or views. Without that information nobody can answer this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're intending to use computed_pay in place of job, but you haven't actually changed the references to job.

I'd also recommend never use NATURAL JOIN. It uses column names to guess at how to join tables, and if you have generic columns such as CREATED_ON or CREATED_BY, it will break and you'll end up re-writing all your SQL.